# Nested loop doesn't bring the desired result

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am fairly new to r so this might be a stupid doubt.

I have a dataframe in which I want to cycle through the rows in a specific column and check if the name in it is in another variable. Although, the value in each row may have more than one name separated by semi-colons.I need to check each one of them. I tried a nested loop but I get a list of the repeated values. My code is described below:

```
# Column in df I want to modify:
company.tickers  
----------
CARD3  
CSAN3  
CVCB3  
ELET3;ELET5;ELET6  
ENBR3  
FESA3;FESA4  
OIBR3;OIBR4  
PETR3;PETR4  
PTBL3  
TUPY3  
VLID3  

# stock names I would like to keep
stocks <- c("CARD3", "TUPY3", "OIBR3", "FESA4", "PTBL3", "VLID3","CNTO3","CSAN3","ELET3","PETR4","ENBR3")

result=list()

# Cycle through rows
for (i in 1:length(df.statements$company.tickers)){

  print(df.statements$company.tickers[i])
  stock.tickers <- strsplit(row,";")

  # Cycle through names in a cell
  for (j in 1:length(stock.tickers)) {

    if (stock.tickers[j] %in% stocks){

      print(stock.tickers[j])

      result <- c( result, stock.tickers[j])

    }

  }

}

# My expected result is the following column:
company.tickers 
----------
CARD3  
CSAN3  
CVCB3  
ELET3
ENBR3  
FESA4  
OIBR3
PETR4  
PTBL3  
TUPY3  
VLID3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
#build regex
stocks.regex <- paste0( stocks, collapse = "|")
#subset using grepl ans the new regex
subset( df, grepl( stocks.regex, df$company.tickers ) )
```

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDF(fread("company.tickers  
CARD3  
CSAN3  
CVCB3  
ELET3;ELET5;ELET6  
ENBR3  
FESA3;FESA4  
OIBR3;OIBR4  
PETR3;PETR4  
PTBL3  
TUPY3  
VLID3", sep = ","))

stocks <- c("CARD3", "TUPY3", "OIBR3", "FESA4", "PTBL3", "VLID3","CNTO3","CSAN3","ELET3","PETR4","ENBR3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt using `tidyr::separate` to temporarily split the tickers column into separate columns. Lengthen/tidy the data and then filter it to get what you want.

I'd be grateful for comments that would help to improve this technique.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))

company.tickers = c(
  "CARD3",
  "CSAN3",
  "CVCB3",
  "ELET3;ELET5;ELET6",
  "ENBR3",
  "FESA3;FESA4",
  "OIBR3;OIBR4",
  "PETR3;PETR4",
  "PTBL3",
  "TUPY3",
  "VLID3")

random.data <- runif(length(company.tickers))
stocks <- c("CARD3", "TUPY3", "OIBR3", "FESA4", "PTBL3", "VLID3", "CNTO3", "CSAN3", "ELET3", "PETR4", "ENBR3")

# construct a data frame
df <- dplyr::tibble(company.tickers, random.data)

# work out how many columns `separate` will need, and create a vector of unusual column names
# it feels weird that we need to do this
# but without this I always get an error from `separate` in the next step

new_cols <- paste0("zqzcol", 1:max(map_int(strsplit(df$company.tickers, ";"), length)))

# temporarily create new columns using `separate`
# then use `pivot_longer` to reabsorb these into long, tidy data
# then filter this by what is in `stocks`
# then tidy up using `select` (optional)

df %>% 
  tidyr::separate(col = company.tickers, sep = ";", into = new_cols) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("zqzcol"), values_to = "company.tickers", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(company.tickers %in% stocks) %>% 
  select(company.tickers, everything(), -name)
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 10 rows [1, 2, 3,
#> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    company.tickers random.data
#>    <chr>                 <dbl>
#>  1 CARD3                0.568 
#>  2 CSAN3                0.0370
#>  3 ELET3                0.119 
#>  4 ENBR3                0.276 
#>  5 FESA4                0.196 
#>  6 OIBR3                0.301 
#>  7 PETR4                0.504 
#>  8 PTBL3                0.712 
#>  9 TUPY3                0.790 
#> 10 VLID3                0.956
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thnx for the answer! I am still getting a different result from the expected: A tibble: 13 x 2, with PETR3 and ELET6 that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Well I have provided a reprex so if your result is different you must be typing something different to what I have provided (or have some significantly different package versions!) Try providing a reprex (search for this if you don't know how) and seeing what happens.

Comment: You have 16 stocks mentioned in the tickers column, and 11 listed in stocks, of which 1 ("CNTO3") doesn't match. So I would have thought you would get a 10-row tibble as desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` alternative to Wimpel's very clever answer:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

company.tickers = c(
"CARD3",
"CSAN3",
"CVCB3",
"ELET3;ELET5;ELET6",
"ENBR3",
"FESA3;FESA4",
"OIBR3;OIBR4",
"PETR3;PETR4",
"PTBL3",
"TUPY3",
"VLID3")

stocks <- c("CARD3", "TUPY3", "OIBR3", "FESA4", "PTBL3", "VLID3", "CNTO3", "CSAN3", "ELET3", "PETR4", "ENBR3")

df <- dplyr::tibble(company.tickers)

filter_df <- function(x, df, col) {
  df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(.data[[col]], x))
}

purrr::map_dfr(stocks, ~ filter_df(., df = df, col = "company.tickers")) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>    company.tickers  
#>    <chr>            
#>  1 CARD3            
#>  2 TUPY3            
#>  3 OIBR3;OIBR4      
#>  4 FESA3;FESA4      
#>  5 PTBL3            
#>  6 VLID3            
#>  7 CSAN3            
#>  8 ELET3;ELET5;ELET6
#>  9 PETR3;PETR4      
#> 10 ENBR3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear or didn't understand the code you guys wrote. The result should have only items that are in stocks. Therefore, "OIBR4", "FESA3", "PETR3", "ELET5", and "ELET6" should be eliminated from the column. My main issue is dealing with rows that have more than one value (separated by semicolon).

Comment: Oh ok - I did wonder about that, but you weren't specific enough in your question. It's often a good idea to mock up an example of what your desired outcome would look like. I started writing an answer that used `tidyr::separate` to split the strings up by semi-colon but then changed tack. I'll try again. Maybe you can edit your question just to be totally clear what outcome you need.

Comment: This answer uses a `map` function from `purrr` to produce the loop process you were asking about in your original question. My other answer doesn't do an explicit loop in the same way.